# How to loop a SASS array contectly

Tags: sass

Could someone explain the correct way to achieve looping a colours array for the next 100 or so divs?

I have a sass array of 5 colours which I would like to apply as the background colour for each post within a WordPress loop. Let's say I have 100 posts how would I repeatedly use each of the 5 colours within colours array?

```
$red: #d20b21;
$pink: #ea4f76;
$yellow: #f7bb05;
$purple: #b81c56;
$orange: #e94f1a;

$colours: (
 red: $red,
 pink: $pink,
 yellow: $yellow,
 purple: $purple,
 orange: $orange,
);

.post{
  &:nth-of-type(1) {
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As aside notice: please remember that `:nth-of-type` pseudo-selector only works with **elements**, not with CSS classes. Please refer [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) on this topic.

Your task can be solved pretty easy by using `:nth-child` instead:

```
$red: #d20b21;
$pink: #ea4f76;
$yellow: #f7bb05;
$purple: #b81c56;
$orange: #e94f1a;

$colours: (
 red: $red,
 pink: $pink,
 yellow: $yellow,
 purple: $purple,
 orange: $orange,
);

.post {
  $index: 0;
  @each $color in map-values($colours) {
    &:nth-child(#{length($colours)}n+#{$index}) {
      color: $color;
    }
    $index: $index + 1;
  }
}
```